# iPhone - class stop seeing superclass' reference

Tags: iphone, class

I have this class where I have something like this on .h

```
@interface myClass : UIImageView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

    @public id referenceOne;
    @public id referenceTwo;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id referenceOne;
@property (nonatomic,retain) id referenceTwo;
```

on .m I have

```
@synthesize referenceOne, referenceTwo;
```

This class has no delegate protocol.

I have other classes that are based on this one. For one of these classes I have defined a delegate protocol and have my implementation file like this:

```
@protocol MyBasedClassDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

- (void) doStuff;

@end

@interface MyBasedClass : myClass {
    id<MyBasedClassDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MyBasedClassDelegate> delegate;
```

and on .m I have

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

as soon as I have defined this MyBasedClassDelegate the class stopped seeing the referenceOne and referenceTwo ids inherited from myClass. Now Xcode says these are not declared. If I disable the protocol, it sees the references again.

Why is that and how do I solve that?

thanks.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
@interface MyBasedClass : myClass {
    id<MyBasedClassDelegate> _delegate;
}
```

rename to

```
@interface MyBasedClass : myClass {
    id<MyBasedClassDelegate> delegate;
}
```

OR

do @synthesize delegate = _delegate;  instead

EDIT:

Works well for me

myClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface myClass : UIImageView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    id referenceOne;
    id referenceTwo;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id referenceOne;
@property (nonatomic,retain) id referenceTwo;

@end
```

myClass.m

```
#import "myClass.h"
@implementation myClass
@synthesize referenceOne, referenceTwo;
@end
```

MyBasedClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "myClass.h"

@protocol MyBasedClassDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

- (void) doStuff;

@end

@interface MyBasedClass : myClass {
    id<MyBasedClassDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MyBasedClassDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MyBasedClass.m

```
#import "MyBasedClass.h"


@implementation MyBasedClass
@synthesize delegate;
-(void) dosmth {
    referenceOne = nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: ok, I have a typo there. Thanks, but I fixed the error and the problem persists...

Comment: weird... I will continue to investigate that. Thanks.

Comment: btw: this is not a very good idea to declare instance variables public, especially when you have access via properties.

Comment: thanks the problem was another typo! grrrrr!!!! The weird part is that I've created it without this other bug when I created it here... anyway, everything is fine now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the variable name "_delegate" to "delegate", I think it might work.  (Alternatively, comment out the synthesize line and it should also work).

I ran into a similar thing earlier today -- if you synthesize properties for instance variables that do not exist, the compiler doesn't complain but for some reason you can no longer see the superclass's variables.

For me it was finding http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/53261-unable-access-superclass-member-variables-subclass-implementation.html that helped.

Comment: ok, I have a typo there. Thanks, but I fixed the error and the problem persists...

Comment: Not sure then.  Sorry.  I copied your provided code, fixed the typo, and it compiles fine for me.